# Android application OutOfMemory. Bitmap

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have an application for android 3.0 and higher where i have to show some large bitmaps.The bitmaps are already scaled to the size in which they have to be displayed. I have already used the `largeheap=true` in manifest file but still i am getting `OutOfMemory` error. I am not using LRU cache right now as mention in [displaying bitmaps efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on developer.android. I have the following doubts.

1. Should i just try-catch the error and do the rest of the work?
2. Do i have to use [bitmap.recycle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) function. After android 3.0 it is not necessary to use [bitmap.recycle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) as the memory is not allocated in native and as mentioned this function frees the native object.
3. Should i use the LRU cache mechanism as mention in [caching bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) ? Wont it increase the memory consumption of my application as i would be storing bitmaps in cache ?
4. Is there any proper example or architecture to display bitmaps that explain the LRUcache mechanism. Reading all the theories on the net is alot confusing.
5. Does the inBitmap field of [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) also help in reducing memory ?

I have memory constraints on my application and i want it to use as less memory as possible. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage the memory and keep the quality is explained in this article on developer android [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) . Hope this answers your query.

Comment: i have read the link mentioned. but i'm confused with above 5 points as there is a lot of theory there.

Comment: I know . But in long term it will help you. I was also stuck with the same problem and it helped me. You will be making many more apps in future and this knowledge will help you. Thats the most efficient way. Good Luck.